# Retrieving metadata of a photo saved to blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, plupload

I am uploading a photo to blobstore using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). The [BlobInfo object](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore#google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo) has some metadata

```
content_type: The content type of the blob.
creation: The creation date of the blob, or when it was uploaded.
filename: The file name that the user selected from their machine.
size: The size of the uncompressed blob.
md5_hash: The MD5 hash value of the uploaded blob.
```

My question is how can I get the other metadata of the photo either from plupload or serverside? Specifically, there is a metadata field of "description" that I need to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [exif-py](https://github.com/ianare/exif-py) as follows:

```
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
blob_reader_data = StringIO.StringIO(blob_reader.read())
tags = exifread.process_file(blob_reader_data)
```

the tags object it returns contain the metadata you're looking for.